# How to detect double shift keypress event in reactjs application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Despite following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707650/detect-double-ctrl-keypress-in-js) stackoverflow thread, I am unable to efficiently detect double shift key press event in my **reactjs** application.

I added,

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyPress);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyPress);
}

handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    how to detect double shift key press, more efficiently?
}
```

Comment: what you mean by double ?? both the `shift` keys pressed at a time or pressing and releasing shift key twice ??

Answer (score 1):

Because with React you have [some limitation to use click & double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777826/onclick-works-but-ondoubleclick-is-ignored-on-react-component) events on the same element, I would do it at my own like this:

Create 3 Variables : 
One for the counter (how often the shift was pressed), and 
One for elapsed time between the Keypress.
State-Variable which notice that Shift was double-pressed

If Key-Event was triggered (BTW: I would use keyup), then you:

- check if Shift-Key was pressed (check by keycode)
- (if yes) increment the counter-variable to `1`

  - and set the `elapsed-time` variable to current timestamp.

If additional Key-Events are triggered also check if shift-key's are pressed.
If `yes`, check if the `current-timestamp` minus `elapsed-timestamp` is in the range of time you've set to notice a double-keypress (e.g. 1 second).
If yes, set your `double-press` variable to 1, if not, clear the counter and `elapsed-time` variable.

Hope this gives you an Idea how to handle that.
At the page I posted in the first line, there are also a tiny example of kind like this Idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449854/1256697